# I am unable to decrement value in stepper using swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistepper

In my project the stepper was not able to decrease the value in textfield is this the correct way of assigning to table view and here for decrementing and incrementing I need to pass the value in parameters to an api here when I click on `+` it was incrementing and updating in textfield but when I click `-` it was not decrementing can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is my code

```
cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
cell.stepper.minimumValue = Double((arr?.quantity)!)
cell.stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperAction(sender:)), for:.valueChanged)

func stepperAction(sender: UIStepper) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        let obj = cartCountModel?.items[(index?.row)!]
        self.itemId = obj?.itemId
        let cell : ProductTableViewCell = tableDetails.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as! ProductTableViewCell
        var value = String(describing:Float(sender.value))
        print(value)
        let quant = value.replacingOccurrences(of: ".0", with: "")
//        cell.quantityTextField.text = String(describing: quant)
        self.quantity = Int(quant)
        print(quantity)
        let itemsAddingApi = "http:xxx......................"
        itemsIncrementingandDecrementingtocartDownloadJsonWithURL(itemsApi: itemsAddingApi)
    }
```

Comment: That code suffers many issues

Comment: thanks for reply I got the issue I am unable to give stepper value so it is not incrementing @Yitzchak

Comment: if possible can u let me know what r the issues remaining in this ? @Yitzchak

Comment: You did the same thing with your username! It has no meaning!

Comment: You will need to fix your code as it has no structure for any one to be able to read it. If I would just guess that you want to increase and decrease the quantity in your app then here is what can be considered:
is quantity a public variable?  where did you define your textfield?